# How can i create a Post for google plus company pages using APIs

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-admin-sdk, google-domain-api

1. What is the difference between user's profile and user stream?
2. what does google apps profile mean?
3. How can I create a Post for regular google plus users or company pages or google apps profile?
4. what is the difference between google domain apis and directory apis.

It was quite easy to integrate with other social platforms like Facebook or LinkedIn, but here I am very confused with all these terms.

And there are many people in the market (Hootsuite, Buffer etc.) who are able to post directly on regular google plus profile or company pages

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: What is the difference between user's profile and user stream?

The users profile describes them as a person name work history.  The stream would be the posts they have made in the past.

> 2: what does google apps profile mean?

Google Apps or [Gsuite](https://gsuite.google.com/together/?user-benefits_activeEl=tab-connect) is a group of tools from google.  A Google apps profile is not the same as a Google+ Soical media profile it is the users profile from within gsuite.

> 3: How can I create a Post for regular google plus users or company pages or google apps profile?

You can not post directly to a regular google plus user or company page.   Using the [Goolge plus domains api](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) you can post to the Google apps (Gsuite) account, these posts will only been seen by other users on your domain they are not public.

> 4. what is the difference between google domain apis and directory apis.

Direcory apis or admin sdk lets you admin the users within the domain account (Gsuite).    Google plus domains api lets you post messages to the users on the domain, like its own social media site.

> It was quite easy to integrate with other social platforms like Facebook or LinkedIn, but here I am very confused with all these terms.

Google+ the social media site is not like Facebook or linked-in there is no public write API for it.  You cant post to it programmatic.

Comment: Then how Buffer/ Hootsuite or other people are able to do that, they can directly post to my google plus profile

Comment: Google has a top secret API that they let some big businesses use.  It is not public.  this is one of them https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/pages-signup  To my knowledge they are not accepting any new I have never been able to get access to it.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, this is what I was missing from start.